# amazon-cognito-identity-js refresh token expiration handling

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, typescript, amazon-cognito, refresh-token

When retrieving the id token via get session, cognito identity js automatically retrieves a new access token with it's refresh token, if the access token has expired. However I want to implement correct handling if also the refresh token is expired, but it's hard to test because the minimum expiration time for the refresh token is 1 day.

It would be nice to know if either:

- There is any other way how i can properly test what happens when the access and refresh token are expired (so I can test redirection to login page)
- Which code path is called or how i can catch the case where the refresh token is expired

Code:

```
getIdToken(callback: Callback): void {
if (callback == null) {
  throw("callback is null");
}
if (this.getCurrentUser() != null) {
  this.getCurrentUser().getSession(function (err, session) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error: " + err);
      callback.callbackWithParam(null);
    } else {
      if (session.isValid()) {
        console.log("returning id token");
        callback.callbackWithParam(session.getIdToken().getJwtToken());
      } else {
        console.log("got the id token, but the session isn't valid");
      }
    }
  });
  } 
  else
    callback.callbackWithParam(null);
}
```

My guess is that `got the id token, but the session isn't valid` will be called, as when the refresh token is valid it automatically refreshes the access token and the session is valid again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When logging in into Kibana i got the following message:

```
com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidp.model.NotAuthorizedException: Refresh Token has expired (Service: AWSCognitoIdentityProvider; Status Code: 400; Error Code: NotAuthorizedException; Request ID: ...)
```

In this case the err branch would be called

```
if (err) {
  console.log("error: " + err);
  callback.callbackWithParam(null);
}
```

So the handling for the expiration of the refresh token is needed to be done there. However, i settled on redirecting the user to the login page in each case except `session.isValid()`

Hope this helps someone out there :)